# Couldn't translate expression value(Microsoft.ProjectServer.Query`1

Tags: sharepoint, project, csom, project-server, sharepoint-2019

Project server 2019 after upgrade from 2016, filter project by ProjectSiteURL throw exception

<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>-1, Microsoft.ProjectServer.PJClientCallableException</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">Couldn't translate expression value(Microsoft.ProjectServer.Query`1[Microsoft.ProjectServer.PublishedProject]).Where(p => (p.ProjectSiteUrl == "http://bing.com")). See InnerException for more details.</m:message>
</m:error>

Get request :
/_api/ProjectServer/Projects?$select=Id,Name,ProjectSiteUrl&$filter=ProjectSiteUrl%20%20eq 'http://bing.com'
Same error appears using C# CSOM
SP2019 v:16.0.10.382.20004